# Efficent way to calculate Top 10, or Top X, list, across multiple time periods

Tags: python, django, sorting, time-complexity, aggregation

What I want to do: Calculate the most popular search queries for: past day, past 30 days, past 60 days, past 90 days, each calendar month, and for all time.

My raw data is a list of timestamped search queries, and I'm already running a nightly cron job for related data aggregation so I'd like to integrate this calculation into it. Reading through every query is fine (and as far as I can tell necessary) for a daily tally, but for the other time periods this is going to be an expensive calculation so I'm looking for a way to use my precounted data to save time.

What I don't want to do: Pull the records for every day in the period, sum all the tallies, sort the entire resulting list, and take the top X values. This is going to be inefficient, especially for the "all time" list.

I considered using heaps and binary trees to keep realtime sorts and/or access data faster, reading words off of each list in parallel and pushing their values into the heap with various constraints and ending conditions, but this always ruins either the lookup time or the sort time and I'm basically back to looking at everything.

I also thought about keeping running totals for each time period, adding the latest day and subtracting the earliest (saving monthly totals on the 1st of every month), but then I have to save complete counts for every time period every day (instead of just the top X) and I'm still looking through every record in the daily totals.

Is there any way to perform this faster, maybe using some other data structure or a fun mathematical property that I'm just not aware of? Also, tn case anyone needs to know, this whole thing lives inside a Django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No.

There is no guarantee that a Top-Ten-Of-Last-Year song was ever on a Top-Ten-Daily list (it's highly likely, but not guaranteed).

The only way to get an absolutely-for-sure Top Ten is to add up all the votes over the specified time period, then select the Top Ten.

Answer (score 0):

Could use the Counter() class, part of the high-performance container datatypes. Create a dictionary of all the searches as keys to the dictionary with a count of their frequency.

```
cnt = Counter()
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
    cnt[word] += 1
print cnt
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

Comment: This would still require looking through all the terms in each period in order to get an accurate wouldn't it? I'm looking for a way to only look at an upper portion of the terms in each period while still ensuring that I get the terms which appear the most. I don't want to define a hard threshold though because Murphy says the first value below it will be the one that has more values cumulatively than something above the threshold, and will therefore be erroneously omitted.

Comment: I was thinking running something on each days searches, which creates a dictionary for each and every day. That would take a long time the first time around, but then you would have the frequencies pretty much precomputed. Also might want to look into the pandas package, its really really good with time series data. http://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it fits with what you're doing, but if the data is stored via a Django model, you can avail yourself of aggregation to get the info in a single query.

Given:

```
class SearchQuery(models.Model):
    query = models.CharField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then:

```
import datetime
from django.db.models import Count

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
days_ago_30 = today - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
...

top_yesterday = SearchQuery.objects.filter(date__range=(yesterday, today)).annotate(query_count=Count('query')).order_by('-query_count')

top_30_days = SearchQuery.objects.filter(date__range=(days_ago_30, today)).annotate(query_count=Count('query')).order_by('-query_count')

...
```

That's the most efficient you'll get it done with Django, but it may not necessarily be the *most* efficient. However, doing things like adding a index for `query` will help a lot.

**EDIT**

It just occurred to me that you'll end up with dupes in the list with that. You can technically de-dupe the list after the fact, but if you're running Django 1.4+ and PostgreSQL as your database you can simple append `.distinct('query')` to the end of those querysets.